# How to diagnose performance issues inside mongodb by using mongostats

Tags: performance, mongodb

I've been using mongostats to diagnose overall activity inside my mongodb instance. How can I use it to also diagnose performance issues / degradation?

One field I'm really interested in learning more about is locked % and expected behavior based on the results from all the other fields.

I feels this feature is kinda vague and needs to be flushed out a bit more.

Answer (score 6):

The locked % is the % of time the global write lock (remember, mongo has a process wide write lock) is taken per sample. This percentage will increase when you increase the number of writes (inserts, updates, removes, db.eval(), etc.). A high value means the database is spending a lot of time being locked waiting for writes to finish and as a result as no queries can complete until the lock is released. As such the overall query throughput will be reduced (sometimes dramatically).

"faults" means that mongo is trying to hit data that is mapped to the virtual memory space but not in physical memory. Basically it means it's hitting disk rather than memory and is an indication you do not have enough RAM (or, for example, your index isn't right balanced). If memory serves this is available on Linux only though. This should be as close to 0 as you can get it.

"qr:qw" are the read and write query queues and if these are not zero it means the server is receiving more queries than it is able to process. This isn't necessarily a problem unless this number is consistently high or growing. Indicates overal system performance is not high enough to support your query throughput.

Most other fields are pretty self explanatory or not that useful. netIn/Out is useful if you expect to be io bound. This will happen if these values approach your maximum network bandwith.